# Получение количества прошедших тестов в Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, pipelines

Есть pipeline в jenkins из которого стартует другая job

```
build job: 'job_name1', parameters: [ string(name: 'name1', value: 'value1') ], propagate: false
```

Job выполняется и в итоге есть N passed тестов, M failed тестов и т.д. вопрос как получить количество passed, failed, skipped и общее количество тестов?

Comment: Используете какие-либо плагины для тестов?

Comment: @Fch JUnit Plugin

Answer (score 1):

JUnit Plugin имеет класс `TestResultAction`, в котором хранятся результаты тестов.
Когда вызывается `build`, то мы получаем объект типа `RunWrapper`. Этот объект можно привести к типу `Run`, у которого есть метод `getAction()`

Что-то вроде этого:

```
import hudson.model.Run
import hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper
import hudson.model.Action

 def(RunWrapper) build = build(job: 'job_name1', parameters: [ string(name: 'name1', value: 'value1') ], propagate: false,)
 def(TestResultAction) results = (build as Run).getAction(TestResultAction) (as TestResultAction)
 def allTests = results.getResult()
 def failedTests = results.getFailCount()
```

В скобочках классы, если писать типизировано.

Документация:

- [RunWrapper](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html)
- [Run](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html)
- [TestResultAction](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/junit/hudson/tasks/junit/TestResultAction.html)

Comment: запускаю
`def build= build job: 'job_name1', parameters: [...], propagate: false`   
`def results = build.getAction(TestResultAction)`
и в итоге получается
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TestResultAction for class: groovy.lang.Binding
 at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)`

Comment: Импорт делали `import hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction`? И не забывайте приведение к `Run` с помощью `build as Run`